# .cls file not found

Tags: installing, document-classes

I'm running Windows 7 and have to run a special class file for my thesis. I've tried holding the file 'tutthesis.cls' in the same directory as the .tex file itself, but that didn't work. I also tried to install the class using method given here: http://docs.miktex.org/2.8/manual/localadditions.html

My code looks like this

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,finnish]{tutthesis}
```

And it gives the error

```
! LaTeX Error: File `tutthesis.cls' not found.
```

Using the local addition method, my root folder was

```
C:\Local TeX Files
```

Which itself looked like

```
C:\Local TeX Files\tex\latex\misc\tutthesis.cls
```

just as given in the example. I've tried naming the directories differently (misc -> tutthesis) but so far nothing has worked, even though I've gone through various similar questions on this site.

I hope I didn't forget any crucial information. Any ideas what might work?

**

EDIT: The log file from a small test document located in the same folder (hopefully this is what you asked for):

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (MiKTeX 2.9) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2014.7.1)  2 JUL 2014 18:08
entering extended mode
**testi.tex
(C:\KOULU\Kandi\LaTeX\testi.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <v3.8m> and hyphenation patterns for english, afrikaans, ancientgreek, ar
abic, armenian, assamese, basque, bengali, bokmal, bulgarian, catalan, coptic, 
croatian, czech, danish, dutch, esperanto, estonian, farsi, finnish, french, ga
lician, german, german-x-2013-05-26, greek, gujarati, hindi, hungarian, iceland
ic, indonesian, interlingua, irish, italian, kannada, kurmanji, latin, latvian,
 lithuanian, malayalam, marathi, mongolian, mongolianlmc, monogreek, ngerman, n
german-x-2013-05-26, nynorsk, oriya, panjabi, pinyin, polish, portuguese, roman
ian, russian, sanskrit, serbian, slovak, slovenian, spanish, swedish, swissgerm
an, tamil, telugu, turkish, turkmen, ukenglish, ukrainian, uppersorbian, usengl
ishmax, welsh, loaded.
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\article.cls"
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\size12.clo"
File: size12.clo 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count79
\c@section=\count80
\c@subsection=\count81
\c@subsubsection=\count82
\c@paragraph=\count83
\c@subparagraph=\count84
\c@figure=\count85
\c@table=\count86
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
)

LaTeX Warning: Unused global option(s):
    [finnish].

(C:\KOULU\Kandi\LaTeX\testi.aux)
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
 [1

{C:/ProgramData/MiKTeX/2.9/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}] (C:\KOULU\Kandi\LaTeX\tes
ti.aux) ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 206 strings out of 493921
 2276 string characters out of 3144874
 49031 words of memory out of 3000000
 3584 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
 3938 words of font info for 15 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
 841 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 22i,4n,21p,137b,107s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s
<C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr1
2.pfb>
Output written on testi.pdf (1 page, 10414 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 10 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

Comment: Imho the name of the class is  tudthesis.cls (with dt and not tt).

Comment: I have no idea where you got that from. The class is definitely named 'tutthesis.cls'. It was created with that name to be used within our university.

Comment: Well a tudthesis.cls exists. And a typo in the name is a quite probable cause of your problem. Did you update the fndb after you put the file in the local tree.

Comment: Oh, that makes more sense now. But yes, I tried updating FNDB and also changing the directory name into C:\Latex\... so that there were no spaces. No difference.

Comment: Where exactly is your tex file? Compile a small hello word document in the same folder twice and show its log-file.

Comment: The .tex file is located at C:\KOULU\Kandi\LaTeX\file.tex. Log-file  from the same folder is edited to the original question.

Comment: I don't see any reason why putting the cls directly in `C:\KOULU\Kandi\LaTeX` shouldn't work - if the file name is correct. And `C:\LocalTeXFiles\tex\latex\misc` should work too -- if the root `C:\LocalTeXFile` has been correctly attached to your miktex 2.9 (and not to another miktex 2.8, or not at all due to some error).

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. I double-checked to make sure the directory is attached to the right Miktex and triple-checked spelling. Still it doesn't work, even in the same directory. Thanks for trying though.

Comment: Can you put the cls and an example document which tries to use and the log-file one of the failed compilation it in a zip-file on the net?

Comment: I came up with the darndest problem. The log-files are empty. Even though they worked quite fine earlier and I have done nothing regarding them, new compilations create empty files. Regardless, here is a download link for a zip. Inside is 1) short example document 2) .cls file 3) files created by compilation. http://wikisend.com/download/233026/testi.zip I tried compiling several other files with that .cls but none appeared to create a real log file. I am frankly quite baffled. So far I'm considering brutally re-installing MikTex just in case.

Comment: Your cls file has the extension txt: tutthesis.cls.txt. So naturally latex can't find it. Rename the file. And tell your windows not to hide known extensions.

Comment: ... I feel such a fool now, quite embarrassing. I did not even consider that the file I got wouldn't be usable straight away. Thank you so much for taking the time!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Windows was once again hiding the file ending.

Comment: Offtopic? Maybe. But Ulrikes suggestion to update the `fndb` (https://docs.miktex.org/faq/maintenance.html)  did the trick for me. Thanks! :)